# sort, copy data from multiple sheets and paste in same sheets at different columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook namely "OPTIONS", having multiple sheets. Data is in sheets no. 4 to 31; in columns A, B, C and D in different multiple rows. All 4 to 31 sheets have different names. In all 4 to 31 sheets, in column C have two names called "CE" and "PE". I want find CE name and copy data from column D ( which is in front of CE ) and paste in sames respective sheets in column F. Same find CE name copy data from column B and paste in column G to their respective sheets. Again now find PE name copy data in from column D and copied data should paste in column H to their respective sheets. Again find PE name copy data from column B and paste in column I. Paste should start from row 2 i.e. below heading.

In conclusion, available data is from 4 to 31 sheets having different names, in column A B C and D. Find two names from column C from all sheets and paste data from D to F, from B to G, from D to H and from B to I; in their respective sheets.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried code for first three sheets and its working fine. But the code will go too long. Expecting short code. I am not understanding how should I post my example code here. Someone please help.

```
    Sub watermasa()
Dim x As String, y As String
x = InputBox("Please Enter the first name")
y = InputBox("Please Enter the second name")

With Sheets("ADANIENT")
.Range("C1:C" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).AutoFilter 1, x
.Range("D2:D" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("ADANIENT").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Range("B2:B" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("ADANIENT").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("C1:C" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).AutoFilter 1, y
.Range("D2:D" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("ADANIENT").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Range("B2:B" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("ADANIENT").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

With Sheets("ADANIPORTS")
.Range("C1:C" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).AutoFilter 1, x
.Range("D2:D" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("ADANIPORTS").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Range("B2:B" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("ADANIPORTS").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("C1:C" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).AutoFilter 1, y
.Range("D2:D" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("ADANIPORTS").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Range("B2:B" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("ADANIPORTS").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

With Sheets("APOLLOTYRE")
.Range("C1:C" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).AutoFilter 1, x
.Range("D2:D" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("APOLLOTYRE").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Range("B2:B" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("APOLLOTYRE").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("C1:C" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).AutoFilter 1, y
.Range("D2:D" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("APOLLOTYRE").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Range("B2:B" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("APOLLOTYRE").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

With Sheets("ARVIND")
.Range("C1:C" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).AutoFilter 1, x
.Range("D2:D" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("ARVIND").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Range("B2:B" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("APOLLOTYRE").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("C1:C" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).AutoFilter 1, y
.Range("D2:D" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("APOLLOTYRE").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.Range("B2:B" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).SpecialCells(12).Copy
    Sheets("APOLLOTYRE").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You should paste the code and afterwards select all of it and hit the brackets symbol. That will format it as a code block

Comment: What is the (3) intended to represent in `.End(3)` ? My VBE tells me that `xlUp` is -4162 but 3 produces the correct row number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the worksheets by walking through an array of their worksheet names or by the ordinal index number of their current position in the worksheet queue.

```
Sub watermasa_by_Name()
    Dim x As String, y As String, lrc As Long, v As Long, vWSs As Variant

    x = InputBox("Please Enter the first name")
    y = InputBox("Please Enter the second name")

    vWSs = Array("ADANIENT", "ADANIPORTS", "APOLLOTYRE", "ARVIND")

    For v = LBound(vWSs) To UBound(vWSs)
        With Sheets(vWSs(v))
            lrc = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("C1:C" & lrc).AutoFilter 1, x
            .Range("D2:D" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("B2:B" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            .Range("C1:C" & lrc).AutoFilter 1, y
            .Range("D2:D" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("B2:B" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    Next v

End Sub

Sub watermasa_by_Index()
    Dim x As String, y As String, lrc As Long, w As Long

    x = InputBox("Please Enter the first name")
    y = InputBox("Please Enter the second name")

    For w = 4 To 31   ' maybe For w = 4 To sheets.count ?
        With Sheets(w)
            lrc = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("C1:C" & lrc).AutoFilter 1, x
            .Range("D2:D" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("B2:B" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            .Range("C1:C" & lrc).AutoFilter 1, y
            .Range("D2:D" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("B2:B" & lrc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    Next w

End Sub
```

I'm not sure why you used the `With ... End With` statement for the copy and not the paste operation but it does clean up your code a bit.

Comment: Jeeped, Both codes working fine as per my requirement. Preferably second one I am going to use because its avoid me to write all sheets name. One more requirement or improvement needed. x = CE and y= PE, does it possible to remove input box and directly can run the code?

Comment: I'm unclear on how you want to remove them. If you are going to hard-code the values for *x* and *y* in then you would simply use something like `x= "Jeeped"` and `y = "Kishor"` ..

Comment: The code is 100% as per my requirement. I am satisfied by this code. I do not have any more questions. Thanks